# Any way to stop previous async loop when clicking button again?

Tags: javascript, loops, async-await, onclick, cancellation

If I append a code of `for loop` in the browser DOM inside `<script>` tag by clicking on a button with `i<50` and then instantly I appended another piece of code with `i<2` by clicking on the Button again , so is there any way to stop the `i<50` execution, is there any way I could stop the previous `for loop` execution?

I tried to solve it , but apparently i don't know enough and could not find any resource online.

First time  click on button:

```
async function onGreenPlayButtonClicked() {
    for (var count = 0; count < 50; count++) {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)); // 1 SEC WAIT
        MinecraftAvatar.sayForNSeconds(greeting, 7)
    }
};
```

Second time  click on button:

```
async function onGreenPlayButtonClicked() {
    for (var count = 0; count < 2; count++) {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10)); // 0.01 SEC WAIT
        MinecraftAvatar.sayForNSeconds(greeting, 7)
    }
};
```

I don't want FIRST loop still be executing when 2nd time button is clicked (when the first loop still executing, i modified code and clicked button again and updates script tag)

Comment: Please create a [mcve] by adding the actual code. Are you dynamically adding `script` tags?

Comment: Yes, but only if the for loop is async, otherwise the button click won't get recognised until the previous for loop is complete.

Comment: @Keith how would you do that ?

Comment: Sure, could you update your question with a working snippet of what you tried.  That way it's a lot easier to show what to do etc.

Comment: @Keith there you go

Comment: Nice one, I'm on mobile at the moment, so can't create a snippet, but the good news is your already doing async loop, so all you need is a flag to stop the loop, what I would do is make your function return a cancel function.

Comment: :( sorry i don't know about how to implement that cancel function , it's okay , i will wait for you  @Keith, till then i will try to incorporate you thoughts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218961/discussion-between-coderboi-and-keith).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'm back at PC now.

Below is a simple working snippet, I basically store a cancel function that gets stored, you can then check to see if it's been set on the green button click, if it is call it.  All this cancel function does is set the local cancelMe flag to true, you can then use this in your for loop to abort..

ps. the greet var, is just there to show it's a new for loop, as I also reset this to 1 so that the count start from 1 again.

```js
const delay = ms => 
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

let greet = 1; //just for debugging.

let cancel;

async function onGreenPlayButtonClicked() {
    if (cancel) cancel();
    let cancelMe = false;
    cancel = () => {
      cancelMe = true;
      greet = 1;
    }
    for (var count = 0; count < 50 && !cancelMe; count++) {
        await delay(1000);
        if (cancelMe) break; 
        console.log('greeting: ' + greet ++);
    }
};



document.querySelector('.green').
  addEventListener('click', onGreenPlayButtonClicked);
```

```html
<button class="green">Green Button</button>
```

Comment: This is good, i am outside right now, i will implemet later so right now i can't give it green check tho.. Thanks for the support bro.